# CoreData NSPredicate - No result for first character in search bar

Tags: swift, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller

im having problem with nspredicate when searching for first character in search bar using fetch result controller (FRC).

Searchbar delegate for updatesearchresult :

```
//UISearchResultsUpdating
public func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController){

    if let searchText = resultSearchController.searchBar.text , searchController.isActive {   Other codes........  }
```

}

My predicate as follows :

```
 let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject", in: moc)!
 let sd1 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "nickname", ascending: false)

 let sortDescriptors = [sd1]
 let fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest<XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject")
 fetchRequest.entity = entity
 fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors
 fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 10

 *fetchRequest.predicate =  NSPredicate(format:"jidStr contains[c] %@ OR nickname contains[c] %@ ", searchText,searchText)*
```

Im using custom sectionkeypath ("searchSection") to separate section *Contacts* and *Group Chats* as follows

```
let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext:moc , sectionNameKeyPath: "searchSection", cacheName: nil)
```

For searchSection, declared as follows

```
dynamic var searchSection: String {

    if(jidStr.contains("+")){
        return "Contacts"
    }else{
        return "Group Chats"
    }
}
```

You can refer to attached images below

[No result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mo3te.png)

[With result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2riCs.png)

I wonder why when second character entered then the result will appear but not with first character for some characters. Hoping anyone can help. Many thanks

Comment: Show code of your searching textfield or search controller delegate method.

Comment: @SagarChauhan hi, i have added searchbar delegate for your references

Comment: i believe it got something with my searchSection , if i pass nil to sectionnamekeypath it would appear the result but i want to divide the section for each result (contacts if phone number while group chats for group). Hope someone will help me. Many thanks